# How to use seaborn.barplot() for negative output?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

Suppose i have a dataframe as follows
:
**Sex = [male, female, female, male, male]** for which **result = [0,1,1,0,1]**

Now **sns.barplot(x='Sex', y = 'result' ,data=dataframe)**  would plot a barplot only for **result==1**. What if I want the plot for **result==0** using the same sns.barplot function?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reversed column:

```
df['new'] = (~df.result.astype(bool)).astype(int)
```

and then

```
sns.barplot(x='new', y = 'result' ,data=df)
```